# Nested loop in rowset

Tags: oracle, jsp

I wrote a jsp where multiple values fetched from rowset is displaced.

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
if (!rset.next())
  sb.append("<P> No matching rows.<P>\n");
else 
{  
sb.append("<table>"); 
        while (rset.next()) 
        {  
        sb.append("<tr>"); 
        sb.append("<td>Case ID :</td>");
        sb.append("<td>"+ rset.getInt(1) + "</td>");
        sb.append("</tr>");
        sb.append("<tr>"); 
        sb.append("<td>Case Type :</td>");
        sb.append("<td>"+ rset.getString(2) + "</td>");
        sb.append("</tr>");
        sb.append("<tr>"); 
        sb.append("<td>Case Date : </td>");
        sb.append("<td>"+ rset.getString(4) + "</td>");
        sb.append("</tr>");
        sb.append("<tr>"); 
        sb.append("<td>Case plot no</td>");
        sb.append("<td>"+ rset.getInt(5) + "</td>");
        sb.append("</tr>");         
         } 
       sb.append("</table>");
```

This code is working fine. Now, my Case Plot no has multiple values for single Case id. I need to show case plot no values in comma, for eg. 1,2,54. How can I do this? I added some code but throws exception:

```
sb.append("<tr>"); 
        sb.append("<td>case plot no: </td>");
        for(int i=0;i<=rset.getString(i).length();i++){
        sb.append("<td>"+ rset.getString(i) + ",</td>");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue resolved. Since **resultset** returns output in matrix-format (i.e row- column). In my query there is only one column so I am using `rset.getString(1)` to get the first column and then in `while(rset.next())`, I am taking the row-values.

Here is the code:

```
while(rset.next())
{
sb.append(rset.getstring(1));
}
```

Hope, this helps.